# VBA prompt for Copy and paste from combo box in active cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Could anyone help me to copy and paste from combo box in active cell and below mentioned code created to copy and paste from drop down in active cell but i need a code to copy paste in any cell where cursor is there

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("Value").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this                                                                                                   `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ActiveCell.Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub `

Answer (score 0):

From comments -

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change() 
ActiveCell.Value = ComboBox1.Value 
End Sub
```

[supersam](https://superuser.com/users/555689/supersam)